# Using straight connectors with screw endpoint?

Tags: mosfet, connector, terminal, wire-terminals, screw-terminal

I am a complete newbie to wiring but have almost completed the install of a MOSFET board on my 3D Printer. Felt it was necessary to avoid potential fires that this particular printer is known for.

I'm on the last step and need to install the positive/negative wires for the hotbed on the MOSFET board. The connectors already on them are straight (can be seen on the black one) but need to go under the metal plate on the board.

Will this be fine or should I cut them and put spade connectors instead? Doing that would void my warranty and the wires are already really short as is, why I would prefer to keep the current connectors if they won't be a problem.

[image]

Comment: Contact should always pass a 5 lb pull test .

Comment: This is not a ducking repair question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Blade connectors are not recommended for screw terminals. You should cut, strip and crimp spade connectors on the wires.** This one minute process will improve the reliability for screw terminal attachment and conductivity. Power conductors will benefit from the proper mechanical connection in terms of electrical resistance and mechanical strength.

Signal conductors are less concerning,  but having a wire pull free is still a concern.

Blade or other non spade or non ring connectors will only have 25% of the contact space and mechanical reliability, if not lower.

**if you have warranty concerns, another option is making adapter cables.** A simple blade to spade adapter cable will prevent the need to cut the wires, will have the typical mechanical reliability of the blade quick disconnect connector while giving you some extra length to the cable. It will be electronically transparent as long as you make it to spec. Just use the right gauge wire and crimp terminals.

Comment: While a lot of this was over my head, I did get the gist and may later go back and crimp some spade connectors on. The bootlace ferrules as the other answer called them seemed to hold pretty well so I went with that for the time being. I've got a lot of wiring in a pretty confined space so next time I take it apart to try and organize, I will likely look to improve that.

Comment: Those arn't bootlace ferrules tho. Those are round cylinder end. Google image bootlace ferrules to see what they really look like.

Comment: I may be wrong but comparing images of bootlace ferrules and blade connectors, these look a lot like bootlace ferrules. Here is another picture I took before I plugged them in http://i.imgur.com/SUp6GWT.jpg Looks just like the first image result for "bootlace ferrules" from Google Images http://www.turnerelectronics.co.uk/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/bootlace_ferrules.jpg

Comment: @brett boot lace ferrules are cylinders. Blade connectors are rectangular flat surfaces. In either case, they are both not appropriate for screw terminals/block connectors as shown. Only spade and ring connectors are good for that terminal.

Answer (score 1):

those type of crimp connector are commonly known as bootlace ferrules. The red wire has got the same connector as the black, so just follow the way that has been connected. You may have to unscrew the cable clamp a fair way to be able to get the connector under the metal clamp plate, but once you've got it in and tightened securely they won't move.
Hope this is of help.

Comment: I had actually stuck the red one in already to see how it would hold. I left the black exposed for the sake of taking a picture. They seemed to stay in pretty well though so I went ahead and went forward with that and everything is working as expected. Thank you for the feedback, makes me feel a bit safer about it, even if I would have preferred swapping them with a spade.